# jquery scroll for dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a case where i require multiple scroll left/right events, normally i use something like :

```
<div class="arrow_left" onclick="/* move_left() */">&lt;</div>
<div id="some_container" class="somecontainer">
<div class="item_container" id="item_container">
<span>item 1</span>
<span>item 2</span>
<span>item 3</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and in my jquery:

```
function move_right() {
var leftPos = $('#item_container').scrollLeft();
if (leftPos < 1500) {
$('#item_container').animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 150});
}
}
```

But in this case i am using multiple instances of **some_container** using **php foreach** and i don't want to define each selector in jquery manually.

is there a way i can solve this problem without using fancy plugins?

thanks
max

Comment: each container will have `arrows` or just the activated one?

Comment: each container will have arrows without being activated

Answer (score 1):

Made a jsFiddle for better explanation: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcbq0ko/

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="arrow_left" onclick="/* move_left() */">&lt;</div>
  <div class="arrow_right">&gt;</div>
  <div id="some_container" class="somecontainer">
    <div class="item_container" id="item_container">
      <span>item 1</span>
      <span>item 2</span>
      <span>item 3</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <div class="arrow_left" onclick="/* move_left() */">&lt;</div>
  <div class="arrow_right">&gt;</div>
  <div id="some_container" class="somecontainer">
    <div class="item_container" id="item_container">
      <span>item 1</span>
      <span>item 2</span>
      <span>item 3</span>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.group .arrow_right').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.somecontainer').html('update');
  $(this).next('.somecontainer').animate({scrollRight: 150});
});
```

You can wrap everything in a div that will separate your controls. Then you'll have individual access for each container. In this example I'm updating entire HTML, but, of course, you will do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.arrow_left').click(function() {
    var newLeftPos = $(this).next().find('div').scrollLeft();
    console.log(newLeftPos);
    if(newLeftPos >10){
     $(this).next().find('div').animate({scrollLeft: - 150});
    }
    else{
        $(this).next().find('div').animate({scrollLeft: + 150});
    }
});
```

and same thing for right arrow :)